# Slow ethernet broadband connection - is my cable wrong?

Tags: broadband, connection

I just bought a [15m cat 6 cable](http://www.cabling4less.co.uk/category.php?terms=cat+6&Go.x=0&Go.y=0&Go=Go) and the connection to my desktop is slow 2-4Mbps.

I have a Netgear DG834 router with the latest firmware that's reporting a 19Mbps connection speed.  My wireless speeds are good and if connect the laptop to it wired I get rocking speeds.  My desktop is a fast machine with a new Win7 x64 build.

Can the cable have such a big influence on the speeds or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cable quality can have alot to do with speeds. I would attempt attaching the previously mentioned laptop using the cable for troubleshooting.  If the connection is still slow, it probably is the network cable, otherwise there is something misconfigured on the desktop or router.

Comment: what an obviously brilliant idea...why couldn't I see that?  Will try and get back you.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, that reproduced the problem. It's slow as hell too. The only remaining question is how can I know where to get a good quality cable (in the UK)?

Comment: I normally use Lindy.co.uk for cables,  but I would send that one back where you got it from as it's not fit for purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Jane, have just ordered one from there. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Update: it wasn't the cable. New cable arrived from Jane's recommendation above and same problem. Also changed router (new one finally arrived today from my new ISP) and I'm now getting 17.6Mbps through the same cable!